# Which version of rpy to instal?

Tags: python, r

I want to use R through Python.  I would like to know which version of rpy to install, it's not clear from the documentation.
I'm on a Mac with OSX 10.5 (leopard).
I use python version 2.7.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try using rpy2-2.2.1. It can be downloaded [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rpy/files/latest/download?source=files)

Comment: The current version is 2.2.7, and there is a rc version of 2.3.0.

Comment: ditto. I have to delete the packages on SF / mark it as outdated. Now I only upload to Pypi (command-line, that's what takes me the least amount of time).